# Qt VS Tools does not work in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I have installed Qt from this file, qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.13.1.exe and install Qt VS Addin from this file, qt-vsaddin-msvc2019-2.4.1.vsix

Unfortunately, Qt VS Tools doesnt work in Visual Studio 2019. I get this
[image]

Here are the full ActivityLog.xml if you are interested.
https://pastebin.com/AXfCEXuF Below are error related to Qt in ActivityLog.xml

```
Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) C:\USERS\DNDT\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\VISUALSTUDIO\16.0_AE768EF4\EXTENSIONS\U15MJQMI.ZYG\QtVsTools.dll    
SetSite failed for package [Vsix]Source: 'QtVsTools' Description: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'at QtVsTools.Vsix.InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress`1 progress)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.AsyncPackage.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<Microsoft-VisualStudio-Shell-Interop-IAsyncLoadablePackageInitialize-Initialize>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.<JoinAsync>d__68.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.RethrowException(AggregateException e)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.InternalGetResult(Boolean ignoreUIThreadCheck)at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.VsTask.GetResult() WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Answer (score 3):

Installing the previous version does the trick. 
https://download.qt.io/archive/vsaddin/2.4.0/qt-vsaddin-msvc2019-2.4.0.vsix

Answer (score 0):

Install "Qt Visual Studio Tools 2.4.2" I am currently using that with Qt 15.13.2, it is built for VS17 but it works on VS19.